# $1/|x|^\alpha$ is integrable on the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ iff $\alpha < n$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, lebesgue-integral

I've always remember the statement that $1/|x|^\alpha$ is integrable on the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ if and only if $\alpha < n$. But I don't know how to prove it. Can anyone show me how to prove it or link a proof of it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You know how to transform an integral into polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: After transforming the integral in general spherical coordinates (see Wikipedia for the transformations) use "when $\frac{1}{|x|^s}$ is summable in (0,1] ".

Comment: Why is this question closed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $A_n(R)$ be the surface area of $\|x\|=R$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then obviously $A_n(R)= C\cdot R^{n-1}$ for some positive constant $C$, and:

$$ \int_{\|x\|\leq 1}\frac{d\mu}{\|x\|^{\alpha}} = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{A_n(z)}{z^\alpha}\,dz = C\cdot \int_{0}^{1}z^{n-1-\alpha}=\frac{C}{n-\alpha}$$
provided that $\alpha\color{red}{<}n$.

Comment: Hi Jack, I have a simple question. For example, in $\mathbb R^2$, is the integral $\int_{\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert \le 1} \frac{d\mu}{\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert ^\alpha}$ defined as $\int_{x_2^2+x_1^2 \le 1}\int_{x_1 \le 1} \frac{d\mu}{\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert ^\alpha}dx_1 dx_2$? I saw such expression $\int_{\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert \le 1} \frac{d\mu}{\lvert \lvert x \rvert \rvert ^\alpha}$ a lot, but I was always confused with its actual definition and I couldn't find one definition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And should we change $d\mu$ into $dx$ in the expression? Thanks.