# If $|f(x)|\leq c|x|^{-\alpha}$ prove $f \in L^1(B_R(0))$ for all $R>0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to solve the following (using only theorems from within Real Analysis, i.e. not using spherical coordinates etc.):

> Let $f$ be measurable on $\mathbb{R^n}$. Let $c>0$ and $\alpha<n$ such that
> $|f(x)|\leq c|x|^{-\alpha}$.
>
> Prove that $f \in L^1(B_R(0))$,  for all $R>0$.

After trying $n=2$ to get a feel for the problem, I've come to realize that:

a. I could simplify by bounding using rectangles instead of $B_R(0)$, since by monotonicity:

$$\int_{B_R(0)} |f(x)|dm \leq \int_{[-R,R]^n} |f(x)|dm \leq \int_{[-R,R]^n} c|x|^{-\alpha}dm$$

b. The crux of the problem is around $x=0$, so if I could split the rectangle into smaller rectangles, such as $\big\{(\frac{R}{2^{l+1}},\frac{R}{2^{l}}]\big\}_{l=0}^{\infty}$ (and similarly for $-R$) then I might be able to get the bound while dealing with $x=0$.

My problem is moving from this intuition to formally obtaining the bound. I considered using Holder but didn't get anywhere with that, and then tried splitting the integral using Tonelli, but this gets messy with $n$ integrals (I'm not even sure how to decide what I am integrating over in each).

I am either in the wrong direction or lacking an understanding of how to formalize the above.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try spherical coordinates?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$1/|x|^\alpha$ is integrable on the unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ iff $\alpha &lt; n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422117/1-x-alpha-is-integrable-on-the-unit-ball-in-mathbb-rn-iff-alpha-n)

Comment: Thanks, but is there no other way that allows for a 'self-contained' solution, i.e. using. theorems and other results from within Real Analysis? (e.g. Fubini-Tonelli etc?). I am not too familiar with spherical coordinates and I doubt this was the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez Agree - clarified that now.

Comment: Is the change of variable theorem a valid one? or Stokes theorem?

Comment: @AitorIribarLopez Change of variables yes. Haven't learned about Stokes yet.

Comment: Your problem has rotational symmetry, because $B(0,R)$ and $1/|x|^\alpha$ are invariant under rotations. Not trying to use this will make your life more complicated. Spherical coordinates are the perfect fit for this situation, because using them you can prove that if $f : B(0,R) \to \mathbb R$ is invariant under rotations, ie if it can be written as $f(x) = g(|x|)$ for some $g : (0,R) \to \mathbb R$, $\int_{B(0,R)} f dm = \int_0^R g(r)A(r)dr$ where $A(r)$ is the area of the sphere $S(0,r)$. Now, regarding your attempt, using smaller rectangles will not help since your problem is (+)

Comment: (+) the behaviour of $f$ near $0$, so you you woul have the same problem when trying to bound the integral on the small rectangle containing $0$. Bounding by rectangles is a good idea to apply fubini, but note that your integrand is a somewhat difficult formula to find a primitive for it. Also, you loose the symmetry I spoke about. The only thing I can come with apart from spherical coordinates is that you indtead integrate over a cylinder and try to use induction in some way.

Comment: (*) spherical coordinates are the usual application of the change of variables theorem

Comment: You could try to check what happens to your integrand in the sets $A_k := \left\{2^{-(k+1)} < |x| \le 2^{-k}\right\}$ .. compare your integral with a series and check when it is summable ..

Comment: Where i can find (book) this result?

Answer (score 1):

A consequence of a simple computation of metric tensors, the change of variables formula, and Tonelli's theorem is that for any Borel measurable $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, \infty]$,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{S^{n - 1}}f(r\omega)r^{n - 1}\,dS(\omega)\,dr.$$
This will immediately give you the answer.