# Is interchanging the integration and differentiation valid here?

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

I want to apply the [Leibniz Integration Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement) to a function $f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ given by (for a compact convex set $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$):

$$f(x,\omega) =\frac{1}{\lVert \omega\rVert_2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\lVert \omega\rVert_2^2}\right)\chi_K(\omega),$$

where $\chi_K(x)$ is an indicator function.

This is to say that I want to justify the equality

$$\partial_x \int f(x,\omega)d\omega = \int \partial_x f(x,\omega)d\omega.$$

Per Wikipedia, this requires

1. $\omega\mapsto f(x,\omega)$ is Lebesgue-integrable for each $x$,
2. for almost all $\omega$, $\partial_x f(x,\omega)$ exists for all $x$,
3. there is an integrable function $\theta(\omega)$ such that $|\partial_x f(x,\omega)| \leq \theta(\omega)$ for all $x$, for almost all $\omega$.

My issue is that $f(x,\omega)$ is "close" to many standard counterexamples to the Leibniz Integration Rule.
While it is different in a way that "helps", its not clear to me if it is enough.

For example, for any $x\neq 0$ it is simple to see that $f(x,\omega)$ is integrable via applying the bound $\exp(x) \geq x^k/k!$ for large enough $k$. This upper bounds $f$ by a polynomial in $\omega$ (it is trivially lower-bounded by 0), and we are integrating over the compact set $K$, so everything is fine.
The other properties similarly are straightforward to establish for $x\neq 0$.

There is a potential problem at $x = 0$ though, leading to the question

> For $K$ a compact convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is $f(0,\omega) = \frac{1}{\lVert \omega\rVert_2}\chi_K(\omega)$ lebesgue integrable?

Of course I am also interested if the other conditions hold, but a negative answer to this suffices to answer my question.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Whether $p(x) := \int f(x,\omega)d\omega$ satisfies the conditions for $\partial_xp(x) = \int \partial_x f(x,\omega)d\omega$.

Comment: Is $n>1$? ${}{}$

Comment: Yes, that holds

Comment: Sorry, I meant $n>3$ (I forgot to take the derivative with respect to $x$)? If so, then yes,

Comment: yes, $n\approx 500$ in settings I care about, so there is quite a bit of room.

Comment: Yeah, for $x\neq 0$ the exponential is enough to make things work. I'm concerned that $x = 0$ might kill things for me though, for similar reasons as to why $y\mapsto 1/y$ is not lebesgue integrable near 0 (though my example is closer to $y\mapsto 1/|y|)$.

Comment: The dominating factor here is ${1 \over \| \omega \|^3 }$, so as long as $n >3$ it is an integrable upper bound for $|f_x|$, so you don't need the $1_K$. (See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1422129/27978, for example, to see where the $n>3$ comes from.)

Comment: yeah that works for condition #3. I am concerned about condition #1 though.

Comment: What is your concern? It is continuous except for $\omega = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat I guess the decay is not good enough to get integrability at infinity, that would explain why the indicator function is needed. Of course singularities are not the enemy here, but heavy tails.

Comment: My concern is that other answers indicate that $\int_{(0,1]}\frac{1}{x}dx$ fails to be lebesgue integrable in 1D (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226114/showing-that-1-x-is-not-lebesgue-integrable-on-0-1)), which might imply that $f(0,\omega)$ fails to be lebesgue integrable.

Comment: In $1$D your originial function is in general not integrable, let alone its derivative. But as copper.hat explained above, if $n$ is sufficiently large, then singularities get less and less serious (pass to spherical coordinates as in the answer he linked).

Comment: I didn't see that link, oops. That answers my question, I'd accept an answer pointing out that $\omega = 0$ isn't an issue for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Well, you could write up a neat answer yourself :) I guess copper.hat would be fine with that too (he has roughly $\infty$ reputation and is probably one of the most chill people on this site).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven The compliment is much appreciated, but few people (including my own children) would describe me as chill :-).

Comment: @copper.hat Then you either represent yourself very differently here on math.stackexchange or I missed some of your heated posts :D

Answer (score 0):

The function does satisfy the desired conditions, at least if $n\geq 2$.
It is first worth mentioning that condition 2 is easily satisfied, as it must only hold up to a countable set of exceptions (so bad behavior at $\omega = 0$ is fine).
This leaves conditions 1 and 3.

Note that for these conditions, we really only need to be concerned with behavior at $x = 0$.
For $x\neq 0$, one can apply a bound equivalent to $\exp(x) \geq x^k/k!$ for large-enough $k$ to get that

$$0\leq\int f(x,\omega)d\omega \leq \int \frac{k!}{\lVert\omega\rVert_2}\left(\frac{\lVert \omega\rVert_2^2}{x^2}\right)^k\chi_K(\omega)d\omega \leq \int k! x^{-2k}\lVert\omega\rVert_2^{2k-1}\chi_K(\omega)d\omega,$$

i.e. this is integrable.
A similar bound holds for $\partial_x f(x,\omega)$ (and for any $\partial_x^if(x,\omega)$, if one allows $k$ to depend on $i$), i.e. one can easily show integrability for any dimension $n$.

For $x = 0$, this argument breaks down.
Fortunately, the barrier to $\int\frac{1}{\lVert\omega\rVert_2}\chi_K(\omega)d\omega < \infty$ (namely the singularity at 0) is not an issue in higher dimensions.
This is because one can see by switching to spherical coordinates (where we assume $f$ is radial for simplicity) that $\int f(x,\omega)d\omega \leq O(1)\int_0^\infty f(\lVert \omega\rVert_2)\lVert\omega\rVert_2^{n-1}\chi_K(\omega)d\omega$, where the constant is the surface area of $S^{n-1}$.
In particular, provided $n-1+(-1)\geq 0$, $f(x,\omega)$ itself will be integrable.
One can check that integrability of $\partial_xf(x,\omega)$ at zero requires no additional assumptions, as it vanishes for $x = 0$, so we solely need $n\geq 2$ overall.

Comment: For the derivative you pick up another factor of $\Vert \omega \Vert_2^{-2}$, so you will need $n\geq 4$ to get $\vert \partial_x f(x,\omega \vert \leq \Theta(\omega)$ with $\Theta$ integrable. Otherwise a very nice answer.

Comment: I computed $\partial_x f(x,\omega) = -\frac{x}{\lVert \omega\rVert_2^2}f(x,\omega)$. At the problematic point $x = 0$ it therefore vanishes, and away from $x = 0$ one should be able to bound it using dimension-independent arguments (namely the large equation environment in the post, leveraging the bound $\exp(x)/x^k/k!$).

Comment: For $x\approx 0$, we get that $f(x,\omega) \approx \Vert \omega \Vert_2^{-2} \chi_K(\omega)$. Thus, $\partial_x f(x,\omega) \approx - x\Vert \omega\Vert_2^{-4} \chi_K(\omega)$. I don't think you can improve this.

Comment: Hmm, I was hoping that the bound $|\partial_xf(x,\omega)| \leq k! x^{-2k+1}\lVert \omega\rVert_2^{2k-3}\chi_K(\omega)$ would help. If there was some way to interpolate between the choices of $k = 0$ (for $x = 0$) and $k = 2$ (for $x\neq 0$) it might work, but the bounding function needs to be integrable for all $x$, so perhaps there isn't a way to do such interpolation.